# display post format text in loop

Tags: loop, gallery, post-formats

If post format is Gallery or another then echo my custom text. Get post format from post id. I want to do like this code in wordpress post loop

```
if (isset(get_post_format(gallery))){
echo 'Gallery';
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_post_format()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_format/) returns the post format slug for either the current post, when used inside a loop, or a given post, when a `WP_Post` object or an integer post ID is passed to it as a parameter.

So, if you're using the function in a posts loop, then you can use it like this,

```
while ( have_posts() ) {

  the_post();

  if ( 'gallery' === get_post_format() ) {
    echo 'Gallery';
  } else {
    echo 'Not Gallery';
  }

}
```

Comment: thank you very much